# How do I reverse a boolean array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I want to reverse a boolean array. `free` is the array. Here's my code:

```
public boolean[][] free = new boolean[6][6];

free = !free;
```

I get an error saying the operator `!` is undefined. What should I do?

EDIT
It is not empty. I just want to inverse the values.

```
public boolean[][] free = new boolean[6][6];
    void initFree(State s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nbcars; i++){
            if (horiz[i]){

                for (int j = 0; j < (len[i]-1); j++)        
                    free[moveon[i]][s.pos[i]+j]=true;


            }
            if (!horiz[i]){

                for (int j = 0; j < (len[i]-1); j++)        
                    free[s.pos[i]+j][moveon[i]]=true;
            }
        }
        free = !free;
    }
```

Comment: i can't think of anything else but to loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get operator ! is undefined simply because Java doesn't define ! operator on a two dimensional boolean array.

One way you could achieve what you want is by iterating over each value and then use the ! operator.

```
for(int i=0; i<free.length; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<free[i].length; j++) 
    {
        free[i][j] != free[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example you can modify for your uses. I included an invert method.

```
public class StackOverflowExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ROW = 10, COL = 10;
    boolean[][] ATwoDBoolArray = new boolean[ROW][COL];

    PutValuesInArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    printArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    invertArray(ATwoDBoolArray);
    printArray(ATwoDBoolArray);

}

private static boolean[][] PutValuesInArray(boolean array[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = false;

        }

    }

    return array;
}

private static void printArray(boolean[][] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(array[i][j]);

        }

    }

}

private static boolean[][] invertArray(boolean array[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if(array[i][j]){
                array[i][j] = false;

            }else{
                array[i][j] = true;

            }

        }

    }


    return array;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method inverts all the values in a given 2-dimensional boolean array.

```
static void invertBooleanArray(boolean[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++)
            arr[i][j] = !arr[i][j];
}
```